# InitializeComponent / ShowDialog and databinding

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5

I'm working with quite complex WPF windows with a lot of controls in it.
In my context, the user experience we chose to have  is to first display the window, then load the data and databind (while displaying a progress bar).

With the help of WPF traces in Visual Studio, I have noticed that databinding is invoked twice before the window is shown :

1. when we call InitializeComponent() which parses the XAML.
2. when we call ShowDialog().

Because there is no data yet, it takes quite some time for the databinding mechanism to try fallback and default values.

In order to speed the display of the window to the user, is there a way to disable the WPF databinding until the window is shown ?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1** :
I have more that 400 controls on the form. The call to InitializeComponent() is taking 700ms to complete. I don't know how much of that is tied to databinding, may be I'm mistaken.

**EDIT 2** :
According to dotTrace profiler, InitilizeComponent() WPF cost is 65.43% divided in :

- 34.25% System.Windows
- 22.57% System.Windows.Markup
- 8.29% Other

**EDIT 3** :
We're down to 272ms for InitializeComponent(). 
We have a lot of converters, [singletons](http://shulearnstowpf.blogspot.fr/2012/04/singleton-value-converters-in-wpf.html) are now used for all of them.

Comment: can you provide numbers in ms at each stage?

Comment: See EDIT 1 for InitializeComponent. ShowDialog will not return until the form is closed, this may be a little difficult to measure.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely.

One straight option would be to remove your data-binding-related XAML markup and do the same thing from code-behind, but only after the window has been shown (or on any other condition you find suitable). See this [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on how to databind in code.

Another option would be to not bind to your "real" data sources directly (it's unclear why that would cause a slowdown, but I 'm taking your word for it) but rather to proxy objects that have an on/off switch: start with the switch turned off, making the proxy return empty datasets, and turn it on after the window has been displayed.

Comment: I have more that 400 controls on the form. The call to InitializeComponent() is taking 700ms to complete. I don't know how much of that is tied to databinding, may be I'm mistaken.

Comment: @omatrot: An easy way to find out would be to remove all bindings. In any case, `InitializeComponent` is responsible for parsing the BAML ("compiled XAML") for your pages, instantiating all the controls and wiring everything up -- basically everything you would typically need to do from code, and what you see in Windows Forms .designer.cs files. 700ms does sound like a lot, but it's impossible to make blind guesses regarding why that happens.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting point. Is binding  time so large?

In `InitializeComponent()` `DataContext` usually is null and it should take milliseconds to resolve binding. The problem likely is in another place.

Using default values in DataBinding mechanism is clear, fast and simple.